# Stripe webhooks returning 307 code in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe and their webhooks in my NextJS application and I'm getting a 307 code when trying to access the billing portal.
The billing portal needs to be created (which returns a URL) then the user is redirected to the portal URL.
I tried to redirect on the client and on the server but I'm facing a different problem.

Redirection from the client:

```
const createBillingPortal = async (tenantId: string) => {
  const body = { tenantId };
  const { data } = await axios.post(Routes.API.BILLING, body);
  return data;
};

export const useCreateBillingPortal = (
  tenantId: string,
  router: NextRouter,
) => {
  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: () => createBillingPortal(tenantId),
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      router.push(data);
    },
  });
  return mutation;
};
```

I post to the endpoint corresponding to the billing portal which returns the URL that I use in my `router.push()`.
In this scenario, I have access to the billing portal (the redirection works) but I'm getting a 307 code so the webhooks do no work.

Redirection from the server:

```
const createBillingPortal = async (tenantId: string) => {
  const body = { tenantId };
  await axios.post(Routes.API.BILLING, body);
};

export const useCreateBillingPortal = (
  tenantId: string,
) => {
  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: () => createBillingPortal(tenantId),
  });
  return mutation;
};
```

Less code because the redirection is done with `res.redirect(300, url)` that I call at the end of my endpoint.
Here I'm getting a CORS error that says that the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is missing. I tried adding the header to my post request but it does nothing.

What is the redirection method that I should use and how do I make it return a 200 code instead of a 307 ?

Comment: You can choose to handle the redirect on the frontend or backend, up to you. When you're handling this on the frontend, where exactly are you getting a 307? 

As for the backend CORS issue, you likely need to review your server's CORS policy

Comment: @LauraT There is a Stripe listen command that returns the code and the name of the webhook and that's where I see the 307 code